# how to view a site in localhost

Tags: iis, localhost

I am working under localhost.

In IIS Manager 7.5, windows server 2008.

After adding a new application in "Application pools", I added a new asp.net web application site using that application pool.

The problem is how can I run that website on localhost to check whether the site is working correctly or not?

People told me that I have to add bindings "domains" for that site and run the site using those domains. But that is not convenient as every time adding a new site on IIS, I need to have a domain to check the result?

I think it should be possible to run the site under localhost somehow but I dont know.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a virtual directory to your default web site within IIS. Point that virtual directory to the directory to which you installed/copied your website.

The you can either browse from IIS or type the virtual directory name (preceeded by localhost/) into your browser address bar.

Comment: right, added the application in default web site, it works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the problems is with "domains" yo do not have to buy domains.  By asigning different port numbers on localhost you can add new bindings.

As I know adding binding is essential for IIS to understand which site should be opened.

For example you can  assign port numbers like 
 80 -default- , 81,82 ... 8090...

Comment: when I add new bindings... I have some option: IP address "all unassigned", port and host name. Did you mean to add port: 81 and hostname: localhost?