# How to preview index.php

Tags: phpstorm

So I am trying to get started with PhpStorm, and have watched a number of the videos.

But I still don't get how to get started with previewing files.

For example:

I create new empty project.

Add index.php and add `echo php_info();` and save it.

What is the next step to view this in a browser?  Am running Windows 2008 Server and IIS is running.

UPDATE

I upgraded my version from 6 to 7 of PHP storm, and it lets you preview the file directly from the IDE with the click of a button.  View | Preview in Browser.  V6 was not letting me do that. That's a better workflow than opening a browser and navigating to the desired page.

Comment: run in browser as `localhost/filename` and it is not `php_info()`, rewrite as `phpinfo()`

Comment: Ok, I updated phpinfo().  But localhost/filename just gives a 404. As noted, am running IIS and there are several other websites running. I don't see how IIS is going to know where my project is.

Comment: may i know the path of index.php file and run in browser as localhost/{path of php file} in root folder

Comment: The Path to the php file is c:\Dev\TestProject\index.php

Comment: So .. this question is about "how to configure IIS to serve my files" rather than about PhpStorm...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to view a site in localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241006/how-to-view-a-site-in-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential answer at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8241006/1681480):

> The simplest way is to add a virtual directory to your default web site within IIS. Point that virtual directory to the directory to which you installed/copied your website.
>
> Then you can either browse from IIS or type the virtual directory name (preceeded by localhost/) into your browser address bar.

Comment: To hint that, close as duplicate. It will also create the link. Don't answer. See as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Well, I appreciate you tidying up, but I don't think the original question deserved to be flagged as a duplicate. And my answer doesn't consist of a link. I thought it might be relevant to their problem, and wanted to give credit to where I got the suggestion. I probably should have posted it as a comment instead.

Comment: You not only linked, but also duplicated (via quoting) the content of an already existing answer you rated as potential. I don't see how that qualifies to leave an answer for that, it's the common scenario of commenting via a link and/or closing as duplicate. OP has confirmed that this answer *is* acceptable which confirms a duplicate. I don't think this is too far off, isn't it? (I might have been a little harsh with the DV sorry for that then)